# Need to change app description for published iOS App

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Do I need to upload a new build[with version change], if I want to alter the app description of the iOS app which is in 'Ready For Sale' status?

Comment: Yep, you need to upload a new build and change the version too.

Comment: You could update the promo text though, which is the first sentence of the description.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because how to use the app store connect web site interface doesn't involve any programming.